# Azure Remote Debugging for Node.js with vscode (/opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory)

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code

I deployed a very simple node.js app to Azure App Service.  When following the instructions for [Azure Remote Debugging for Node.js](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging) with vscode, the Azure App Service output shows the following

```
2020-09-02T16:02:16.678769053Z NodeJS Version : v12.16.3
2020-09-02T16:02:16.678773153Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2020-09-02T16:02:16.678777453Z 
2020-09-02T16:02:18.191711485Z flag provided but not defined: -remoteDebug
2020-09-02T16:02:18.192282589Z Usage of oryx:
2020-09-02T16:02:18.195307112Z cat: /opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory
2020-09-02T16:02:18.202078362Z Running 
2020-09-02T16:02:18.203044169Z /opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 51: /opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory


2020-09-02T16:02:19.848Z ERROR - Container hooks-endpoint_3_1647a827 for site hooks-endpoint has exited, failing site start
```

and the remote debugging session fails to start. Why is this failing with the output `/opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory` shown above? I was able to SSH into the web app and find `/opt/startup/startup.sh`

Answer (score 0):

After trying, using `Windows` or `MacOS`, remote debug node webapp cannot be realized.

I think this is a bug. I [have submitted an issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues/1764), and also raised a support ticket on portal.

There is no good solution so far, and I need to wait for the official team to investigate the cause. If there is any progress in the follow-up, I will leave a message for you in this post.